# Lauterbach always steps into timer isr

Tags: debugging, assembly, embedded, lauterbach

I am new to the Lauterbach debugger (Trace32) and seem to have made some unintended changes that complicates my debugging.

In the Lauterbach debugger is it possible to disable tracing and debugging for parts of the code?

In my case, every time I step from a breakpoint I jump into a timer-isr. This makes it very hard to single-step the code. Is it possible to disable timer when a breakpoint is hit?

The same with the `Trace.List` where I almost only see timer-isr code.

I'm not interested in the timer-isr at all and would like to step and trace the application code.

If I remember correct I didn't have this problem before and I might have changed some configuration in Trace32.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found the answer for doing this in Trace32:

```
setup.imaskasm on
setup.imaskhll on
```

Answer (score 0):

You have not said what the processor is, but often (or even invariably) the debug controller for a particular part can be configured to to stop timer peripherals while stopped on a breakpoint.  This will stop the timer interrupt becoming pending every time you stop on a breakpoint.

Comment: Yes, this is exactly what I want to do. Question is how to do this in Trace32. Processor is a Freescale K70.

Comment: @jortan:  I am speaking generally - I do not use Lauterbach, but the debug controller is an on-chip peripheral, if you cannot configure it via the JTAG you can code it directly in your application perhaps with conditional compilation so it only does that for debug builds.